# Is it a bad practice to use an object as a Builder's only field instead of mimicking the class fields?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

I see this sometimes:

```
class SomeClass {
  Object param1, param2, param3, param4;

  private SomeClass(){}      

  static class Builder {
    SomeClass someClassInstance = new SomeClass();

    // standard builder code
  }
}
```

VS this:

```
class SomeClass {
  Object param1, param2, param3, param4;

  private SomeClass(){}      

  static class Builder {
    Object param1, param2, param3, param4;

    // standard builder code
  }
}
```

I prefer the first version very much but I've seen a lot of code using the second version. SESE is nagging me about not enough details but... the question is this simple, so sorry about the useless text. :/

Comment: Meh.  I'm not a big fan of the Builder pattern anyway.  It's a whole lot of boilerplate code for dubious benefit.

Comment: Builder is for complex objects, which means : lot of fields and some of those fields are themselves complex objects that need to be instantiated too. Don't use it for others purpose it's a loss of time.

Comment: Looks absurd to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the main reason to use a Builder, in my mind is that it allows you to make your member variables final without requiring every creation to pass in those parameters to a constructor or factory method all at once.

Your example shows your member variables as non-final and package-protected.  Making the variables final and private is preferable.  In my code, I always make all members private and I will make them final unless there is a specific need for them to change.  Then when I look at the class, I know right away that these non-final variables are special and where my troubles will likely be.

But I don't really use Builder.  The fact that creation of a single object is so complicated that we need another class to create instances of it is a smell, IMO.  I don't mean to say that there aren't reasons to manage the creation of instances.  For example, you might want to reuse instances.  Do some housekeeping with an external resource or thread synchronization.  But if it simply that there are too many parameters and/or they interact with each other in complex ways, my first thought is that there is too much going on in the constructor.  The first thing I would consider is whether composition would allow for things to be grouped more logically.

I do like the fluent interface concept which seems to flow from this idea.  I'm just not a fan of using it to get around the fact that there are too many parameters crammed into a single constructor.

Comment: I like your answer except from the last paragraph, which is too much of a generalization for me. There are definitely valid use cases for the Builder pattern making the code cleaner, most obvious one is StringBuilder. I also came across various XmlBuilders and recently I used a builder to construct HTTP requests with great success.

Comment: @larsbe I was tempted to put weasel words in that sentence but I can't recall ever using this pattern in a design.  I don't think StringBuilder is really an example of this pattern, despite the name.  StringBuilder is really just StringBuffer with synchronization removed.  It solves a different type of issue but I grant you the form is very similar.  Doc Brown has a link to the chapter in Effective Java in his answer if you are unsure about this.

Comment: I see your point regarding StringBuilder and agree. However, I reread the last paragraph and it still bugs me, especially "The fact that the class is so complicated that we need another class to create instances of it is a smell, IMO." This implies that you consider any creational pattern including factories as a smell, where I again disagree.

Comment: @larsbe I've added more detail.  Let me know if this still doesn't address your concerns.

Comment: Builders - particularly fluent ones - are great for building up objects representing configurations, expressions etc. but I agree that they are most widely used to mask heinous SRP violations.

Comment: +1 This gives much more context. It's still possible to disagree, but I see your point now. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This makes so much sense...

I use the builder pattern in Android for intents though. I usually have a static class called BundleBuilder inside my Activity class which creates a Bundle with all the extras I need for that specific Activity.

Not sure if you're familiar with Android, but it would be cool to think what's your opinion on this use case.

Comment: @user932178 I am not really familiar with this.  I just skimmed through some stuff and if I understand correctly, you are using an object to allow you to simplify putting things together to pass on to a framework.  To me this is more of a fluent interface.  It's a subtle distinction, to be sure.  My understanding of the Bloch Builder pattern is "I have 25 parameters in my constructor so I'll put a Builder in."    If I understand, this is really the right way to use patterns.  Conform the techniques to your problems and not the other way around.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing. I might ask another question to get some feedback on this specific use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about [Bloch's builder pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2), not the GoF builder. Its purpose is to avoid the "telescoping constructor" problem, especially for **immutable** objects. Applied to your example, this leads to

```
class SomeClass {
  private final Object param1, param2, param3, param4;

  private SomeClass(Builder builder){
      param1=builder.param1;
      param2=builder.param2;
      param3=builder.param3;
      param4=builder.param4;
  }      

  static class Builder {
    Object param1, param2, param3, param4;
    public Builder(...){
         // complex code to initialize param1 to param4
    }

    public SomeClass build() {
         return new SomeClass(this);
    }
  }
}
```

So as you see now, your first variant will simply not work that way, since you cannot create an instance of the immutable class `SomeClass` as a replacement for the mutable parameter variables. If the class `SomeClass` is not immutable, however, it is debatable if there is a need for a separate `Builder` class.

Answer (score 1):

**How do the two approaches compare ?**

Intuitively, the first approach seems logic: you create an empty object, then you fill its fields using proper methods to invoke the appropriate setters, and at the end you return the final object.

But as pointed out by [Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1204/robert-harvey) in his comment: what's the benefit then ?  Why use a builder and not directly create the object and fill its fields with the appropriate methods ?

There are however cases where this approach does not work.  For example, if your complex `SomeClass` object has only constructors that requires parameters that must first be build.  In this case, you must first create the constructor's parameters and then, at the end, invoke the constructor.  Here, only the second approach can be envisaged.

In fact this second approach seems to be a popular technique when a constructor has [too many parameters](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html).

**What's the purpose of the builder design pattern ?**

According to the [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), the intent of the builder pattern is to:

> separate the construction of a complex object from its representation,
>   so that the same construction process can create different
>   representations.

The idea is to construct an object step by step with:

- an abstract builder interface for creating the parts,
- concrete builders implementing this step by step interface for specific representations, and offering a function to assemble and get the end product,
- a director which gets the concrete builder by injection and invoke it to build the parts as required.

**How does your builder relate to the Builder design pattern ?**

Both approaches (and especially the second) are builders, in the sense that they build objects.  The second is slightly more flexible.

However, neither of these are builders according to the GoF:  there is no builder abstraction here that would dictate a standardized building interface on several classes that obey the same construction logic.  I therefore wonder if this is really worth the added complexity, especially if the constructor takes no argument, and the different objects envisaged are not too complex to build.

Comment: I think the OP talks about Bloch's builder, not GoF's builder. See my answer.

Comment: @DocBrown yes, the article I refer to is indeed about Bloch's solution for constructors with many arguments. I was not aware that this popular solution was officially called "builder" as well, as the term: thanks for the info.  I find it nevertheless confusing as the term  "builder" also frequently refers to the GoF one.  I'll reorder the paragraphs